# PDF Javascript - Setting field values

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm just getting into Javascript and I'm working on editing a pdf for a charactersheet in a rpg me and some friends play, for ease of use. I want it to fill in forms automatically - and so far I've gotten it to work, but I'm wondering if there isn't a way to condense my code a bit and make it less repetitive?

```
var one = this.getField("Stat.0.0");
var statfield = this.getField("Text100.0.1");

if(one.value=="1"){
statfield.value="-30";
}
if(one.value=="2"){
statfield.value="-20";
}
if(one.value=="3"){
statfield.value="-10";
}
if(one.value=="4"){
statfield.value="-5";
}
if(one.value=="5"){
statfield.value="0";
}
if(one.value=="6"||one.value=="7"){
statfield.value="5";
}
if(one.value=="8"||one.value=="9"){
statfield.value="10";
}
if(one.value=="10"){
statfield.value="15";
}
if(one.value=="11"||one.value=="12"){
statfield.value="20";
}
if(one.value=="13"||one.value=="14"){
statfield.value="25";
}
if(one.value=="15"){
statfield.value="30";
}
if(one.value=="16"||one.value=="17"){
statfield.value="35";
}
if(one.value=="18"||one.value=="19"){
statfield.value="40";
}
if(one.value=="20"){
statfield.value="45";
}
```

Any tips on cleaning this up?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `switch()` instead `if` statements. Don't forget `break`'s:

```
var one = this.getField("Stat.0.0").value();
var statfield = this.getField("Text100.0.1");

var oneval = one.value;
switch (oneval) {
    case "1":
        statfield.value = "-30";
        break;
    //case...
    case ("1" || "7"):
        statfield.value = "5";
        break;
    //case...
    default:
        break;
}
```

or (notice `break` only on `case "7"`):

```
switch (oneval) {
    //case...
    case "1":
    case "7":
        statfield.value = "5";
        break;
    //case...
}
```